# Regex don't match previous matches?

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have a string "aabb", I am looking to match (a, b, ab). I want to prioritize longer matches, and not match a match twice.

e.g. output would be a, ab, b

I tried have the following:
`[(\bab\b)|(a)|(b)]` & `[\b(ab|a|b)\b]`

But it outputs a, a, b, b

Comment: What about `ab|[ab]`? `\b` indicates a word boundary. You don't have word boundaries around `ab` in your string.

Comment: The longest comes first `ab|[ab]` means match `ab` or match any character in `[ab]` (so either `a` or `b`)

Comment: Regular expression implementations scan input strings from left to right. So matches will always be given in that order.

Comment: or you can do `(a?b?)`

Comment: @revo That matches the empty string, though. (Might or might not be relevant)

Comment: Yes and I didn't think it would be problem. @Bergi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) in your regex don't match in your input. Just use only

```
/ab|a|b/
```

Comment: Could be shrunk to `ab?|b`

Comment: @revo Yeah, I wanted to keep it simple and obvious